# cron executing twice based on day of the week

Tags: unix, cron

I have a question. We have a cron job that executed on the 15th of this month:

```
min hr day month day_of_week
35  13 15  6     6
```

However, it executed again on June 22nd (which was the 6th day of the week). Would the day_of_week take precedence over day & month that was already set before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While normally the job is executed when the time/date specification fields all match the current time and date, there is one exception: if both "day of month" and "day of week" are restricted (not "*"), then either the "day of month" field (3) or the "day of week" field (5) must match the current day

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

So it happens only in June, at 13:35. Additionally it needs to be EITHER the 15th of June, or the 6th day of the week. Both at once will work too.

Running `man 5 crontab` will give you some additional information, they recommend you use [`test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) to specify both a specific date and restrict the weekday :

> Note:  The  day  of  a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of month, and day of
>          week.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be  run  when  either  field
>          matches the current time.  For example,
>          ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus
>          every Friday. One can, however, achieve the desired result by adding a test to the command (see  the
>          last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).
>
> [...]

```
# Run on every second Saturday of the month
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

Comment: So you think give the setup, repeat of the cron is possible? Since the day of the month & day of the week are both restricted, it would work on either of the dates.

Comment: Yes. It will run again on 29.06.2013 13:35, because that will meet the requirements of minute, hour, month, and day of the week.

Comment: thanks. So how do we say that run only on 15th of the month. Do we put * for the day of the week?

Comment: Yes. If you want to run it on the 15th of ANY month, not only June, also put * for month.